# Const-correctness confusion with non-mutating collections

Tags: c++, const-correctness

Assume that I have a `Widget` class and a collection of `Widget`s:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    void mutate() {}
};

class WidgetCollection
{
private:
    std::vector<Widget> vec;

public:
    Widget* findNiceWidget() { /*...*/ }
    const Widget* findNiceWidget() const { /*...*/ }
};
```

`WidgetCollection::findNiceWidget()` gives access to one of the `Widget`s in the collection that fulfills some criteria.

Now, I have a class `WidgetTags` which allows to assign tags to `Widget`s. Tags are not part of `Widget`s, but are stored outside in this class:

```
class Tag {};

class WidgetTags
{
private:
    std::multimap<const Widget*, Tag> tags;

public:
    void addTag(const Widget* w, Tag t) { /*...*/ }
    std::vector<const Widget*> getWidgetsWithTag(Tag t) const { /*...*/ }
};
```

The class only deals with pointers to `const Widget`s as it never changes any `Widget`, it just associates additional data with them.

Then I introduce three functions to work on these structures.

```
// Takes Widgets from the WidgetCollection and assigns tags to them in an instance of WidgetTags
void tagWidgets(const WidgetCollection& wc, WidgetTags& wt)
{
    Tag niceTag;
    wt.addTag(wc.findNiceWidget(), niceTag);
}

// Prints all Widgets which have the niceTag tag
void printNiceWidgets(const WidgetTags& wt)
{
    Tag niceTag;
    for (auto w : wt.getWidgetsWithTag(niceTag))
        std::cout << w;
}

// Calls a mutating function on all Widgets which have the niceTag tag
void mutateNiceWidgets(const WidgetTags& wt)
{
    Tag niceTag;
    for (auto w : wt.getWidgetsWithTag(niceTag))
        w->mutate();
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that `mutateNiceWidgets()` obviously cannot call `mutate()` as it only has const access to the Widgets returned by `WidgetTags`, even if I pass `WidgetTags` as a non-const reference.
To solve this, I would have to rewrite `WidgetTags` to store pointers to non-const `Widget`s and provide them with a non-const `getWidgetsWithTag()`. But if I do that, then `WidgetTags::addTag()` would have to accept pointers to non-const as well.
And if I do *that*, then I get problems in `tagWidgets()`, which would then have to accept a non-const reference to `WidgetCollection`, which in my opinion is incorrect, as it is not supposed to alter the collection (and in fact, the calling code might not even be able to provide a non-const reference).

I am confused as to how const correctness is supposed to be applied in this situation.

In my use case, all `Widget`s are managed and owned by the `WidgetCollection`. So theoretically, you should be granted non-const access to a `Widget` if you have non-const access to the whole `WidgetCollection`, no matter how you obtained the `Widget`.
Which makes me think about implementing something like this:

```
class WidgetCollection
{
    // ...

    Widget* makeNonConst(const Widget* w)
    {
        return const_cast<Widget*>(w);
    }
};
```

And rewriting `mutateNiceWidgets()`:

```
void mutateNiceWidgets(WidgetCollection& wc, const WidgetTags& wt)
{
    Tag niceTag;

    for (auto w : wt.getWidgetsWithTag(niceTag))
        wc.makeNonConst(w)->mutate();
}
```

But this feels extremely wrong.

Any thoughts on how to make the right choice about what should be const and what shouldn't are appreciated.

Comment: Given that the collection stored widgets in a vector, how do your widget pointers, in the tag collection, deal with the vectors' contents' reallocations, when they happen?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is simplified from the real code. Assume that the vector is reserved large enough, or that the collection is completely populated before the other code runs, or that the vector stores unique_ptr<Widget>.

Comment: If "the collection is completely populated befoire the other code runs", then each widget can simply be identified by its index in the vector, neatly side-stepping the whole issue.

Comment: What do you reckon about: 1) changing `tags` to `std::multimap<Widget*, Tag> tags`, 2) making `getWidgetsWithTags` private as well and returning `std::vector<Widget*>`, 3) tag, print and mutate are public methods of `WidgetTags`, 4) tag and print are const methods, mutate is not. In the end, if you are allowing to mutate widgets within a `WidgetTags` you probably want to store them as non const pointers.

Comment: @rturrado Thanks. However, I don't think it's sensible to move the free functions into `WidgetTags`. I don't want to inject all the actions I potentially want to perform on tagged widgets into this container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pointers for two reasons; identity and access control.

Start with this:

```
struct WidgetId;
```

it is abstract for now (not virtual abstract; but we don't specify what is in it.  Do make it a regular value type however).  A `WidgetId` names a widget uniquely.

Now `WidgetTags` is a multi-bimap between identities and tags.

```
WidgetId findNiceWidget() const { /*...*/ }
const Widget* getWidget(WidgetId) const { /*...*/ }
Widget* getWidget(WidgetId) { /*...*/ }
WidgetId getWidgetId(Widget const*) const { /*...*/ }
```

and your problem goes away.

Now, `WidgetId` could just be an integer, or a `Widget const*`, or whatever internally.

But by splitting access from identity, your problem goes away.  And if widget storage isn't as simple, the end user doesn't notice.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I added a type for identification (which involved some extensive rewriting of code) and the problem disappeared. Thanks also to @SamVarshavchik who suggested something similar in the OP comments (using a vector index).

Comment: @TorbenL. A more extreme solution is to move over to completely value semantics and remove identity completely.  ;)  That would require more extensive reworking of your code, however.